# Django - filter ManyToManyField?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm not sure the best way to describe what it is that I'm trying to do so forgive my title.

I have two models, User and Group.  Group contains field, members, which is a ManyToManyField referring to User.

Given a User, I want to find all of the Groups to which that user belongs.

My idea would be to do something like this:

```
groups = Group.objects.filter(user in members)
```

Something like that.  Even though I realize that this isn't right

I tried reading through this link but couldn't figure out how to apply:
http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#spanning-multi-valued-relationships

Thanks

EDIT:

Figured it out
groups = Group.objects.filter(members__username=user.username)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the user  and you want to have his groups then start querying from it, not the way around ;)

Here's an example:

```
james = User.objects.get(pk= 123)
james_groups = james.group_set.all()
```

Comment: I believe this would only work if you set related_name='groups' attribute on the ManyToManyField

Answer (score 1):

The most concise way is probably

```
groups = user1.group_set.all()
```

which gives you a queryset that is iterable.